# C# Visual Studio Debugger UI behavior with lock

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a block of code in a lock:

```
lock (obj)
{
  //...
}
```

I also have a property that locks on that same object. Simple enough scenario. My question is, if I put a breakpoint inside my locked block of code, and then examine the property in the Visual Studio debugger, what will happen? Will the debugger deadlock until I continue executing after breakpoint (or kill visual studio/debugging)? Or will the debugger simply not show any data for the property (grabbing data in background thread from UI?)

The reason I ask is I've got a property specifically (and only) for debugging purposes; I'm OK with it occasionally not showing data when this scenario happens, but having crashed the debugger (and visual studio) many a time with bad debugger attributes, I'd rather avoid code that could at some point hamper my debugging efforts when that's what I'm trying to aid to begin with!

I plan on testing this at some point when I've got some more time, but was hoping for a quicker answer from someone who might know better.

Comment: I swear you could have tested this in a fraction of the time you spent writing the question.

Comment: I wouldn't worry less about crashing the debugger - that's for the Visual Studio team to worry about. I would be more worried about my multithreaded synchronization points being valid. You should spend your time writing multithreaded unit tests.

Comment: @Charles I admit, after typing it out the question became much simpler than I originally was thinking in my head, but at that point, setting up a test was more work than throwing out the work put into post and hoping for quick answer :P

Comment: The answer is no, it won't deadlock. I don't know how the debugger works, but I'd guess debuggers are treated as a special case by the runtime (or the operating system) and aren't subject to these locks. Perhaps the debugger is seen as being the same thread that it's debugging (a thread can't block itself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the debugger executes watch expressions on a separate worker thread that's running inside the process.  Which will hit the *lock* in your property getter and block.  The debugger puts up with that for 5 seconds, then declares the watch expression unusable and displays "Function evaluation timed out".

The debugger then gets grumpy, not much it can do with that blocked thread, you'll commonly see "Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation."  Which is good advice.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds about what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 2):

No the debugger will show you the properties of the object even if it is within a `lock()` block.

Lock()ing the object does not actually prevent any access to the object - it simply creates a semaphore that will block any *other* code that attempts to lock the same object until the lock is released.

Comment: I think what the OP was saying is that the get{} method for the property also locks on that object, and the question is if the designer uses the property getter to show you the property value, will it be blocked when trying to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that the VS.NET debugger does freeze from time to time, but it must have some deadlock detection and debug optimizations to avoid these types of issues.