# VS2010 debugger in limbo

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a large multithreaded C# program in development that loads multiple DLLs from several VS2010 projects/solutions. Debugging it proves more difficult than I expected (who'd think).

The problem is as follows. More often than not, after a few step-over and/or break-all operations, the program (or perhaps the debugger) enters into some kind of indeterminate state which is neither running nor stopped. In the `Debug` menu, both `Continue` and `Break All` are grayed out, so I cannot continue to work with the program.

Sometimes, but not always, when this happens, I see a message in the watch windows that says:

> Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out.

The program doesn't seem to be running (no output, no stopping on breakpoints...) and doesn't appear to be stopped also (the `Watch` window is grayed out, the `Call Stack` window is empty).

`Stop Debugging` and `Restart` commands are available and working.

Can I do anything in order to be able to debug the thing normally, without restarting the session over and over again?

I am new to development in the Windows environment, and could be missing something obvious.

Comment: Sounds like a dead lock or infinite loop. Have you tried taking a memory dump and examining the program state that way?

Comment: @ConradFrix: I want to be able to stop and examine my program, at the source code level, in whatever state of execution it is. I had a chance to use a few debuggers in the last 20 years, under various flavors of Unix, and every single one of them can do that, infinite loop, deadlock or whatever. And now I have to resort to memory dumps? Under **Windows**, of all things? Please say it ain't so.

Comment: @ConradFrix: In addition, the debugger often enter this state after a simple step over a very simple line of code, without any function calls that could possibly loop or deadlock. So that could not be a reason.

Comment: *the debugger often enter this state after a simple step over a very simple line of code* Perhaps its not the line of code you're debugging   but something [in your watch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8408430/11947).

Comment: Hm. I'm pretty sure no expression in my watches could possibly deadlock or loop, but removing all watches seem to solve the issue, for now at least. Even if there's a bad watch expression somewhere, that's pretty sad. A debugger should not stop working if there's a bug in my program...

Comment: well its sounds like you asked the debugger to do something that wouldn't end. If this is correct there's nothing it can do, barring a solution to the halting problem, except timeout and give you a message. It would be nice if it gave a better message though.

Comment: I ask the debugger to execute an infinite loop all the time. The break button just breaks it... unless the loop happens to be in a watch, in which case the break button is grayed out, the watches are grayed out, and my entire debugging session is trashed. Pretty dumb if you ask me.  By the way please write it as an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: @ConradFrix: I have tried to reproduce this behavior with a small example, and failed. Whatever I put in a watch, infinite loop, deadlock, whatever --- VS behaves as expected. That is, it tries to evaluate the watch for some time, then gives up and continues normally. Break All and Continue are available (not at the same time obviously) and do what they should do.

Comment: when you suggested that I make my comment an answer I decided I would but only if I could repro it. I couldn't do it either in the few minutes I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Conrad Frix said, your best option may be to take a memory dump & examine what your threads are doing. There are a number of tools available for Windows & .Net development, each of which brings something a little different to the table:

[Windbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx) - Text based memory inspection. Great for digging deep into the framework/OS & examining thread stacks, but there's a pretty steep learning curve. (Doesn't get more powerful than this however)

[JetBrains dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) - integrated with Reshaper if you use that. Not the best results in my experience though.

[RedGate ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) - My favorite of the "modern" GUI based profilers. This gives you really good insights into what your threads are doing, but can be a bit difficult to work with if you have hundreds of threads in your application.

Jetbrains & RedGate are paid products, so you'll probably need to use their free trials to resolve your issue.