# "Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out." - in vs2012

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012

Recently I started working on VS2012.

When I debug my code (this is a SharePoint 2013 application) and trying to get the value of variables - I get again and again the message:

```
Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out.
You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation.
```

I previously worked in visual studio 2010 (for SharePoint 2010 applications) and almost never got this message while trying to get the value of variables in the Quick Watch.

I Googled the error message, and I saw that the problem occurs when trying to get a value of functions whose action takes a long time,
But I'm not trying to get a value of functions, only variables, and yet I get this error.

I do not always get the error on the same variables, but random - each time different variables.

Is anyone else having this problem **specifically in VS2012**?

And how can I get rid of it?

Comment: You should post some relevant code.

Comment: @AndyG - But it does not happen always in specific code section, **this is exactly the problem.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Visual Studio Debugger UI behavior with lock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407700/c-sharp-visual-studio-debugger-ui-behavior-with-lock)

Comment: @HansPassant - I do not see there where you have an answer to my question - how can you make the debugger of vs2012 behave like VS2010,
How to cause it not make the variables unusable so fast?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787334/how-to-keep-visual-studio-debugger-visualizers-from-timing-out as the answer states you can increase the time out values under the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Debugger`

Comment: @AquilaSands - I see that I have identical values ​​in the timeout registry keys of 2010 and 2012, So I think something else is causing it to be so short.

Comment: I suggest @Abdur Rahman's Answer as THE ANSWER.

Comment: @banana gor answer for this question...???

Comment: I usually get this when Visual Studio decides it wants to load symbols when I type something in the watch window on a computer that doesn't have a SSD; it's hard to predict and irritating. It would be nice if I could specify additional symbols to load before debugging, but I know VS as an x86 process probably has tight limitations for how many pdbs it can load at once (even though I have plenty of RAM).

Answer (score 9):

> Why this is happening ?

It seems this kind of bug can happen simply when you are trying to watch at some variables who have to be thread safe but sometimes this framework implementation is not perfect....

To avoid this problem : when stepping through code where variables are bound to windows or other controls, you don't show local variables or "auto" variables.  Look at such things only when you are sure your variables are all safe to look at.  And note that the error doesn't necessarily appear on the unsafe variables. Use the "immediate" window on safe (i.e. non-control) variables when operating in dangerous code.

**Data accessors should always be thread safe.** But sometimes between two implementations (let's say between Sharepoint 2010 and Sharepoint 2012 or two version of the .NET framework), this rules is sometimes not true... There is some examples between VS2003 and 2005...

> How can I increase the timeout ?

You can increase the timeout by changing the values of the registry Key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Debugger` using `RegEdit`.

Don't forget to restart Visual Studio after changing the registry key.

Comment: Exit VS 2012 BEFORE changing the registry keys. Otherwise VS will restore the values at exit.

Comment: I am also wonder what the names of the keys you're talking about. In the registry branch you've pointed out is a bunch of a keys.

Comment: I suppose it´s `NormalEvalTimeout`, however there´s also an timeout for the quickwatch and the immediate window.